# minecraft server eula.txt not recognized

Tags: server, minecraft

I'm running a minecraft server on a linux server and a week ago everything worked fine. Yesterday, I tried restarting the server and I got the error message "You need to agree to the EULA in order to run the server. Go to eula.txt for more info.", even though, I agreed to the eula in the .txt file. I tried remaking the eula.txt file myself and I tried letting the server recreate the eula.txt but none of this worked. This is what my .txt file says:

```
#By changing the setting below to TRUE you are indicating your agreement to our EULA (https://account.mojang.com/documents/minecraft_eula).
#Wed Jul 24 13:56:00 CEST 2019
eula=true
```

I read to some forums on the internet but none of the solutions worked for me. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these things:

**-** Give "everyone" access to the eula.txt, maybe the server is not allowed to read eula.txt. > `chmod 777 eula.txt`

**-** Add this parameter. >> `java -jar SERVER_FILE -Dcom.mojang.eula.agree=true`